# error: src refsoec master: no concuerda con ninguno error: fallo el push de algunas referencias GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-push

que tal gente bonita, buen día. Les tengo una pregunta, resulta que estoy tomando el curso de Git y GitHub de Platzi y me salió un error al poner el comando `git push origin master`, les comparto una captura de pantalla de mi terminal por si alguien sabe que debo hacer en este caso.

De antemano muchas gracias por su apoyo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La rama de tu repo se llama "main" pero tu estás intentando hacer push a una rama "master" (que posiblemente no exista)

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Im Guzmn te cuento yo los comandos que uso son los siguientes y te explico para que sirve cada uno.

1. **git status**  Es para ver los cambios que tengo.
2. **git add .** Es para agregar dichos cambios.
3. **git commit -m "Mensaje del commit"** Es para crear el Comit.
4. **git pull origin main** Esto lo que hace es descargar el codigo de la rama de origin y a la vez me hace un merge de mis cambios con dicha rama.
5. **git push origin main** Esto me sube todo el codigo con el merge ja realizado.

Si tienes varias ramas entre el pull y el push tendras que ir cambiandolas. Espero que te haya servido de ayuda. Te puede fallar porque no hayas echo el **git add .**